# Create an array using class members

Tags: c++, class, friend

In my `.hpp` file I have two classes definitions:

```
class c1
{
    protected:
        int size;
        ....
    public:
        read_data() { }
}

class c2
{
    friend class c1;
    public:
        void method() { }
        ...
}
```

Then, in the `.cpp` file I declare the functions

```
void c1::read_data()
{
    ....
    file >> size;
    ....
}    

void c2::method()
{
    int array[size];
}
```

But when I try to define the `size` of the vector I get an error message that says that `size` needs to be a constant. The problem is that I get the value of `size` in an external file so I cannot declare as a constant.

Any ideas in what I can do to solve this?
I consider also using structs if necessary.

Comment: You should use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Comment: You can't use arrays like that. C++ does not work this way. You must use `std::vector`.